# I get an error whenever I try runnning my mcp client

Tags: java

I'm trying to run my mcp (minecraft coder pack) client in eclipse. I'm on macos catalina and I get this error all the time
Here is my error

```
[19:41:45] [Client thread/INFO]: (Session ID is token:0:Player380)
[19:41:48] [Client thread/INFO]: LWJGL Version: 2.9.2
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGILL (0x4) at pc=0x00007fff2dba7abc, pid=21640, tid=9731
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (16.0.1+9) (build 16.0.1+9-24)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (16.0.1+9-24, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, bsd-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [AppKit+0x3e5abc]  -[NSOpenGLContext setView:]+0xe5
#
# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/palmtrww/Desktop/ce poopy/jars/hs_err_pid21640.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#``
```

Comment: LWJGL uses some native libraries, if I remember correctly, so try an older JDK -- JDK 11 would be a good start

Comment: What does the error report file (`/Users/palmtrww/Desktop/ce poopy/jars/hs_err_pid21640.log` ) with more information say?

Comment: Ok i'll try using an older jdk